# Get value of RangeType input field in Django forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

In my django form I wanted a slider type field. So I used NumberInput widget, code below.

```
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput
class RangeInput(NumberInput):
    input_type = 'range'

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    ....
    class Meta:

        model = Application
        fields = ['amount', 'reason']
        widgets = {
            'amount' : RangeInput(attrs={'max': 100000,
            'min':10000,
            'step':5000}),

        }
```

Above helped me to get a slider in my form. Pic below.
[image]

Slider is fine but I want to current value of the slider also to be shown. One way is to manually do using Javascript. Does Django gives a more automatic solution for this?
Without showing the value of the slider to the user, the slider is virtually useless.